# Jena Fuseki and SHACL

Tags: jena, fuseki, shacl

I am having trouble creating a new Jena Fuseki dataset that exposes a SHACL endpoint.

I have built an assembler file based on the [docs](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/shacl/index.html) (see below) and it works fine when I place it in the /fuseki/configuration folder and restart Jena Fuseki. However, when I try to create a new dataset by sending an HTTP POST request to `/$/datasets`, as described in the [HTTP Administration Protocol documentation](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-server-protocol.html), I get an `Error 400: Multiple names given in description of Fuseki service`. The service and each of the endpoints have a `fuseki:name` and this seems to be the problem (although it shouldn't be).

I hope it makes sense. Does anyone know of a workaround?

```
PREFIX :        <#>
PREFIX fuseki:  <http://jena.apache.org/fuseki#>
PREFIX rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX tdb:     <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2008/tdb#>
PREFIX tdb2:  <http://jena.apache.org/2016/tdb#>
PREFIX ja:      <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2005/11/Assembler#>

<#service>
    rdf:type                                fuseki:Service ;
    rdfs:label                              "Dataset with SHACL validation" ;
    fuseki:name                             "ds" ;
    fuseki:endpoint [ 
        fuseki:operation fuseki:query ; 
        fuseki:name "sparql"
    ] ;
    fuseki:endpoint [
        fuseki:operation fuseki:query ; 
        fuseki:name "query"
    ] ;
    fuseki:endpoint [
        fuseki:operation fuseki:shacl ; 
        fuseki:name "shacl" 
    ] ;
    fuseki:endpoint [
        fuseki:operation fuseki:update ; 
        fuseki:name "update" 
    ] ;
    fuseki:endpoint [
        fuseki:operation fuseki:gsp-r ; 
        fuseki:name "get" 
    ] ;
    fuseki:endpoint [
        fuseki:operation fuseki:gsp-rw ; 
        fuseki:name "data" 
    ] ;
    fuseki:endpoint [ 
        fuseki:operation fuseki:upload ;
        fuseki:name "upload"
    ] ;
    fuseki:dataset <#dataset> .

<#dataset> 
    rdf:type                                ja:MemoryDataset .
```

I have used the latest verson (3.13.1) of Jena Fuseki.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed report. The analysis is correct. It is not related to SHACL. Any use of fuseki:name on an operation will trigger it . Recorded in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-1794

Comment: Pull request submitted: https://github.com/apache/jena/pull/649

Comment: This is now fixed in the development codebase.

Comment: @AndyS I have encountered a new problem. The /data endpoint doesn't work with the above configuration. I can insert new triples with an insert query but in my setup I use the data endpoint quite a lot. Any idea why it is not working?